# How do I initialize the fengyuanchen jQuery cropper plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my web application, I am trying to implement a profile picture upload which allows you to crop your image once it is uploaded. To do this, I am using the jQuery cropper plugin found here: http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

The problem is, I just can't get it to initialize! In the documentation, it states:

> Initialize with $.fn.cropper method.

I am not sure what this means, however I know it is important because with my current code:

```
$('#profile-image').cropper({
  aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
  crop: function(e) {
    // Output the result data for cropping image.
    console.log(e.x);
    console.log(e.y);
    console.log(e.width);
    console.log(e.height);
    console.log(e.rotate);
    console.log(e.scaleX);
    console.log(e.scaleY);
  }
});
```

I am greeted with the error:

> TypeError: $(...).cropper is not a function

Any help is appreciated! I understand that I am most likely missing some fundamental understanding of JS and jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check attentively your scripts order. From documentation from github it says

**Installation**

*Include files:*

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script><!-- jQuery is required -->
<link  href="/path/to/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/path/to/cropper.js"></script>
```

So the first idea is that in your code the `cropper` included before `jQuery` or your script to call `cropper` executed(included) before `cropper` script

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've already made sure that cropper is included after jquery!

EDIT: Wait, hold on. The script where I executed the cropper function was included before the cropper script! I'm such a fool!